# Cannot running Eclipse android project to BlueStack

Tags: android, eclipse, connection, bluestacks

I am trying to running/debug my first android project in Eclipse ADT with BlueStack, tried these way

```
1. adb connect localhost
2. adb connect localhost:5555
3. Show view -> Devices
4. Open perspective -> DDMS
```

No BlueStack device when select device
[image]

But

[image]

Comment: edit your manifest and add min sdk level to below your blue stack device.

Comment: Could you say it more clearly? In my manifest, min SDK version is 23

Comment: try to set it as ... 
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>`